# Google-apps-script snippet throwing error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

First, my apologies for a lousy (but accurate) title. I'm trying to take the value of cell AB9 and put it in to cell C9 -- in the same sheet!

Simple, right?

But when I try to run the script, the snippet throws a "Range not found" error, and I can't understand why. (Yeah, it's a PIC error.) Here's what I've got:

```
    // The following three lines copy the last date in the pay period (cell 
    AB9) to the cell just to the left of "last Thursday's" date

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var source = ss.getRange("PRIVATE Current Tracking Sheet!AB9");
    source.copyTo (ss.getRange ("PRIVATE Current Tracking Sheet!C9"), 
    {contentsOnly: true});
```

(The code above is only a small part of a large 225 line script. The code above starts on line 49 and ends on line 54.)

I have checked my syntax and wording, looked at misspellings and anything else I could find, including SO.)

Can someone help a noob? Thanks to everybody.

Comment: Questions looking for help on code that isn't working should include a [mcve].  In this case it could be a good idea to include a demo spreadsheet including the references, in this case a sheet named `PRIVATE Current Tracking Sheet` having `C9` and  `AB9` cells.

Comment: Look at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZUvwBl6aZsCjRlUwwdKvFTOMUfQLsi_61W7aPTQ8meg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Your sheets are named "Sheet1" and "Sheet2" in the sheet that you've just linked.

Comment: Thanks to everybody! (Yeah, it was a PIC error.) The sheet names were wrong in the script. Fixed it! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: What does "PIC" stand for?

Comment: "PIC" stands for "Problem In Chair"

Answer (score 0):

The [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZUvwBl6aZsCjRlUwwdKvFTOMUfQLsi_61W7aPTQ8meg/edit?usp=sharing) shared by the OP shows that the sheet names are Sheet1 and Sheet2

[image]

Instead of `"PRIVATE Current Tracking Sheet!AB9"` use `"Sheet1!AB9"`. Apply the same to the other range reference.